Alphabetize English terms: sort lines but ignore "the" or some other strings
How can I use :sort (or some other command) to sort (case-insensitive) a set of lines while ignoring the if it occurs at the beginning of the line?
I want this:
the house
pen
ball
the dog
Pen

to become this:
ball
the dog
the house
pen

but the output of :sort on its own is:
ball
pen
the dog
the house

Ideally, the solution would allow any arbitrary list of words to be ignored when they come first (e.g., the, a, an).

Have you read :help :sort? What did you try?

I would do:
:sort i /\v\c^((the|a|an)\s+)?/

The i flag tells the :sort command to ignore the case.
The pattern tells the :sort command to ignore what it match. The \v\c^((the|a|an)\s+)? pattern captures the 'small' word at the start of the line (i.e. the, a, an but also The, A, An).
More information with :help :sort

What about words like theory or ants? I'd propose an improvement but unfortunately, I'm a bit in a hurry right now.

@Friedrich Thanks for you hint, I have updated the solution accordingly :-)

Casing may matter, as well.

@romainl, Thanks I have updated the solution accordingly.

I would personally use a word boundary at the end
